# Is there a timing difference between defining time_t at first in function or after other declarations/definitions?

Tags: c, timing

Lets assume this is my log function:

```
int log(const char *fmt, ...) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    int i;
    char buffer[1024];

    i = 0;
    /* code here */
}
```

vs

```
int log(const char *fmt, ...) {
    int i;
    char buffer[1024];
    time_t now;
    
    now = time(NULL);
    i = 0;
    
    /* code here */
}
```

I want to know if the first case is important to get the exact time for the log line. Or is it not that much relevant.

How much time does the program need to allocate 1024 bytes on the stack? (Is there a way to analyse that by gcc or do I have to use clock() calls?)

And what about time critical software?

I think the second part has better readablity. Any minds?

Comment: `time` has 1 second resolution.  You won't notice a difference.

Comment: "Stack allocation" is done by the compiler during compilation (the code emitted referencing the current value of the stack pointer. Does this help?

Comment: Note that "allocation on the stack" isn't the same as doing heap allocation (e.g. via `malloc`). To establish a stack frame, the stack pointer register is just decremented. That is, the time is a single machine instruction.

Comment: Allocating on the stack takes no time. When the function is entered, all the memory for the stack is allocated at once. The exception is variable-length arrays, which aren't allocated until the declaration is reached.

Comment: What may take time is initialization. But unless the initialization contains references to previous variables, it can be done in bulk when the function is entered.

Comment: If you want to see what's happening, put both versions of the code into godbolt.org and compare the generated code.

Comment: PS: merely defining (local) stack variables does NOT generate executable code.

Comment: @dbush your right, I use struct timeval because I have an option to print milliseconds too. But thanks to the rest for clarification. I did not know how the stack really works. I think I will stick to it.

Comment: Note: `time_t` is an integer in POSIX but C leaves the format "unspecified", so it could be a floating point or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack allocation is performed upon entering the function scope, and it is very cheap, typically a single instruction subtracting the allocated space from the stack pointer, if any code at all.  Calling `time(NULL)` before or after this will have no measurable impact, especially given the limited precision of the `time()` function which returns a number of seconds as an integer.

The second approach is more readable and seems preferable.